# Casting from generic to main type

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

I have an `Author` object (extends `IModel`) that is sent to a generic method:

```
IModel author = new Author() { ... };
(new Base).Method(author);
```

and the `Base` class method:

```
public void Method<T>(T obj) where T : IModel {

    //does stuff
    AddToList(obj);
}

private void AddToList<T>(T obj) where T : IModel {
    if(obj is Author)
    {
        var temp = (Author)obj; // <-- this is where the error comes up
        //does stuff
    }
    else if(obj is SomethingElse)
        //...
}
```

How can I cast back from a generic type (`T`) back to the main Type (`Author` or anything else that the `typeof` matches?

Comment: did you try obj as Auther?

Comment: This is not generic code.  And should therefore not use generics.  Use *object* or *dynamic* instead.

Comment: What error do you get? That should work. If `obj is Author` then you should be able to cast it as you are attempting to.

Comment: @HansPassant fixed for future viewers, thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the line with `obj as Auther`. It should work.

Comment: Microsoft and their shortcuts, it works! Thanks! I'll approve when I can.

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx

Looks like you need a temporary object first.

```
class MyOtherClass
{...}

class MyClass<T> 
{

   void SomeMethod(T t)
   {
      object temp = t;
      MyOtherClass obj = (MyOtherClass)temp;

   }
}
```

Comment: While it is a valid solution, I just needed something like @Ankit Vijay suggested. I knew it could've been done, but I honestly forgot how to do it. Research didn't show results. Thanks very much anyway!